# Install liferay 6.1 artifacts into maven repository by ant script

Tags: maven, ant, liferay

i want to use some liferay artifacts in my project(2 change Jboss Portal 4 liferay,but it's other story). I download maven liferay plugin from source forge.net/proj ects/lportal/files/Liferay%20Portal/6.1.0%20GA1/liferay-portal-maven-6.1.0-ce-ga1-20120106155615760.zip/download which should after typing ant install auto automatically install liferay artifacts into maven repository(didn't change anything in build.xml, direction also, couse i want to instali it into default repository USER/.m2. So i type ant instal -debug in cmd and i get this error

```
install-artifact:
Class java.util.Vector loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Equals loaded from parent loader (
parentFirst)
     [exec] Current OS is Windows 7
     [exec] Executing 'mvn.bat' with arguments:
     [exec] 'install:install-file'
     [exec] '-DartifactId=portal-client'
     [exec] '-Dfile=dist/portal-client.jar'
     [exec] '-DgroupId=com.liferay.portal'
     [exec] '-Djavadoc=dist/portal-client-javadoc.jar'
     [exec] '-Dpackaging=jar'
     [exec] '-DpomFile=dist/portal-client.pom'
     [exec] '-Dsources=dist/portal-client-sources.jar'
     [exec] '-Dversion=6.1.0'
     [exec]
     [exec] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
     [exec] not part of the command.
Execute:Java13CommandLauncher: Executing 'mvn.bat' with arguments:
'install:install-file'
'-DartifactId=portal-client'
'-Dfile=dist/portal-client.jar'
'-DgroupId=com.liferay.portal'
'-Djavadoc=dist/portal-client-javadoc.jar'
'-Dpackaging=jar'
'-DpomFile=dist/portal-client.pom'
'-Dsources=dist/portal-client-sources.jar'
'-Dversion=6.1.0'

The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
not part of the command.
     [exec] [INFO] Scanning for projects...
     [exec] [INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'install'.
     [exec] [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
-----------
     [exec] [INFO] Building Maven Default Project
     [exec] [INFO]    task-segment: [install:install-file] (aggregator-style)
     [exec] [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
-----------
     [exec] [INFO] [install:install-file {execution: default-cli}]
     [exec] [INFO] Installing C:\liferay-portal-maven-6.1.0\dist\portal-client.j
ar to C:\Users\Wro00427\.m2\repository\com\liferay\portal\portal-client\6.1.0\po
rtal-client-6.1.0.jar
     [exec] [INFO] Installing C:\liferay-portal-maven-6.1.0\dist\portal-client.p
om to C:\Users\Wro00427\.m2\repository\com\liferay\portal\portal-client\6.1.0\po
rtal-client-6.1.0.pom
     [exec] [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
-----------
     [exec] [INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
     [exec] [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
-----------
     [exec] [INFO] Total time: < 1 second
     [exec] [INFO] Finished at: Wed Jul 11 10:12:03 CEST 2012
     [exec] [INFO] Final Memory: 3M/254M
     [exec] [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
-----------
     [exec] 'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
     [exec] operable program or batch file.
  [antcall] Exiting C:\liferay-portal-maven-6.1.0\build.xml.

BUILD FAILED
C:\liferay-portal-maven-6.1.0\build.xml:221: The following error occurred while
executing this line:
C:\liferay-portal-maven-6.1.0\build.xml:271: exec returned: 1
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:646)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:672)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:498)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
        at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:197)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(Single
CheckExecutor.java:38)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)

        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExe
cutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Total time: 2 seconds
```

I think that i have all envinorment variables like JAVA_HOME, ANT_HOME also M2 and M2_HOME and everything is in PATH also, even i have MAVEN_OPTS. I never use ant i don't know what 2 do. I try looking for answer but can't find this error(exec return 1) in this specific example.

Answer (score 1):

## Option1: Repository manager

I suggest that you install a Maven repository manager like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) and load the jars there. Most repo managers have a GUI to help you loadup needed jars.

It's always a good idea to use a repository manager! The local repository is really a cache.....

## Option2: Install plugin

Call the Maven command-line at the end of your ANT build to install jars into your local repository, for example:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=myapp.jar -DgroupId=?? -DartifactId=?? -Dversion=?? -Dpackaging=jar
```

Comment: I was thinking about nexus but i solve problem changeing failonerror=false. I know that this solution sucks but it build succesfull and i have all lib in local maven repository.